# Access value in JsonConverter.CanConvert()

Tags: c#, json, serialization, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

Is it possible to convert a `string` to a `TimeSpan` object using a custom `JsonConverter`, but have it only convert when the string is in the format `"hh:mm:ss"`?

I've looked at building a custom `JsonConverter` but the `CanConvert()` method only accepts a `Type` object, so there's no way to return `false` if the string is not in the `"hh:mm:ss"` format.

Comment: And what would you want to happen when the string is *not* in the format `hh:mm:ss`?

Comment: It should not apply the conversion.

Comment: I don't understand sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that `CanConvert` only deals with Types and so you cannot make the converter conditional on specific JSON values.  However, you said that your desired behavior is that the conversion from string to `TimeSpan` is not performed if the format does not exactly match `hh:mm:ss`, which I take to mean that you would expect the `TimeSpan` in your deserialized object to have a default value of zero, correct?  In that case, you could just make the `ReadJson` method in the converter do the same thing, i.e. return a default `TimeSpan` if the format does not exactly match:

```
public class TimeSpanConverter : JsonConverter<TimeSpan>
{
    public string TimeSpanFormat { get; set; } = @"hh\:mm\:ss";
    public TimeSpan DefaultTimeSpan { get; set; } = TimeSpan.Zero;

    public override TimeSpan Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        string timeString = reader.GetString();
        if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(timeString, TimeSpanFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out TimeSpan timeSpan))
        {
            return timeSpan;
        }
        return DefaultTimeSpan;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TimeSpan value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString(TimeSpanFormat));
    }
}
```

Here's a short program to demonstrate usage:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"
    {
      ""TimeSpan1"": ""15:46:03"",
      ""TimeSpan2"": ""3:04""
    }";

    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
    options.Converters.Add(new TimeSpanConverter());
    var foo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Foo>(json, options);
    Console.WriteLine(foo.TimeSpan1.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
    Console.WriteLine(foo.TimeSpan2.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));
}

public class Foo
{
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan1 { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan TimeSpan2 { get; set; }
}
```

Output:

```
15:46:03
00:00:00
```

Comment: But I only want the conversion to happen if the string is in the required format. If it's not, then the conversion should not happen at all ie. no default value. A string not in the required format should just stay a string.

Comment: How would you represent that property in your class then?  `TimeSpan` and `string` are not compatible.  Would you declare the property as `object`?

Comment: yeah it would be object.